# Устранение излишних запросов на сайте

Tags: php, оптимизация, mysql

Приветствую

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['zapros'])){
    //тут у нас запрос к базе, который возвращает массив $massiv;
    $_SESSION['zapros'] = $massiv;
}
```

Знаю, так делать неправильно, совать в сессию все запросы. Но в силу того, что 'мне хватает' - использую. Вопрос прост, как на сайте организовать уменьшение запросов от одного пользователя? Мой способ, из эры динозавров - сунуть в сессию. Но правильно ли это? Есть модная штука memcache, но никто не объяснит чем оно лучше той же сессии.. вот допустим у сессии лимит 128мб на всех пользователей (зависит от хостинга), а у мем кэша есть недостатки?

Поможете разобраться?

p.s. да, знаю можно вообще заранее подготовленные данные из файла читать. меня интересует чисто кэширование запросов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memcache >>>>>>>>>>>>> сессия. Как можно догадаться, мемкэш держит все в памяти, а сессия сохраняется на диск - скорости будут просто несопоставимы. Тем более, не будете же вы для каждого пользователя писать список десяти последних новостей, например? Ну и первое, что вас должно было смутить: сессия - это штука, созданная исключительно для работы с пользователем.
По-хорошему кэширование должно быть встроено уже на уровне дб или модели, когда опциональным аргументом метода указывается, что запрос может быть закеширован.

Comment: Мне казалось сессия тоже в памяти! Для каждого пользователя выводятся данные взятые при первом заходе на сайт. Сейчас как: чел зашел -> ему в сессию вписываются данные 1 раз (не все ест-но, а часто запрашиваемые и статичные), и далее он гуляет по сайту. Вот если memcache - чем то явно лучше, буду перебираться на мемкэш. Хотя сам, вот серьезно, разницы по скорости не заметил

Comment: @mixalef, нет, вы даже можете найти файлы сессии, подсмотрев session\_save\_path. Она пишется только один раз за скрипт, и на небольших проектах действительно будет давать минимальный оверхед, в большом проекте можно столкнуться с нагрузкой на диск. У вас нет в этой ситуации критичных преимуществ одного над другим, но кэшировать данные в сессии с целью уменьшить время выполнения запросов - это неправильно. Вы либо ничего не выиграете, либо сломаете архитектуру приложения, начав совать в сессию вещи, которые никак к ней не относятся. Плюс сожрете сессиями кучу места на диске.

Comment: Супер! Теперь понял. Буду юзать мемкэш

Answer (score 0):

По-умолчанию MySQL умело кеширует на своей стороне запросы, если скорость с сервером MySQL высокая, то этого обычно достаточно.

Если же нужно кешировать на стороне PHP, то лучше всего использовать хорошие ORM к примеру Doctrine.

Comment: т.е. между сессией и мемкэшем лучше выбрать - ORM Doctrine? Все же хотел узнать про мем кэш, предпочитают его или сессию. Да и ORM Doctrine - куда данные пишет не понять, в ту же память? Так не медленнее ли это чистой сессии?